# SSAS calculated member not showing as percent while refreshing the excel cube

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ssas, mdx, pivot-table

I created a new measure in the SSAS cube which calculates the % difference in the amount and the format is set as "percent" in the SSAS solution. My front end is excel 2010, I already have the excel pivot table report ready with all the other fields that were created earlier.

My issue is when I refresh the excel report and pull the new measure, the values are not showing up as %.However, when I create a new connection and new pivot table report, it is showing up.

I tried to change the value field settings of the measure to percentage. But when I deselect the measure and select again, it is not preserving the %, it is showing as decimal number

Can anyone suggest a quick work around for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Annoying! If, as you say, the format is correct when you create a new pivot table, I'm pretty sure you'll find that recreating the whole thing is quicker than trying to patch up the old one.

Comment: I agree, but a lot of users have some views set up with this report. If I recreate the whole thing, I should send this report again to all users. I thought it would be easy for me to add measures and ask them to refresh the cube to see the new measures. But the format for % isn't showing correctly

Comment: When I right click on the measure name on the pivot table, there is an option "Value Field Setting" where we can change the value field settings. I am deselecting the measure because I want to try if I select it back would it display the same format as it was earlier